# Align two-lines title

Tags: titles, frontespizio

I've the following title in my thesis' first page:

[image]

I've used the package `frontespizio`. The title is generated using:

```
\Titolo{Explaining overbidding in first price \protect\\ interdependent values auctions using}
```

What I want to obtain is the world *price* to be aligned to the world *using*. I mean, I want that the first line end where ends the second line. How can I do that?

MWE:

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,twoside,openright,titlepage]{book}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[italian,english]{babel}
\usepackage[suftesi]{frontespizio}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage[big,rilegatura=1cm]{layaureo}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,amsthm} 
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage[titles]{tocloft}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{indentfirst} 
\usepackage{ragged2e} 
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{adjustbox}
\usepackage{makecell}
\usepackage{booktabs} 
\usepackage[flushleft]{threeparttable}

\raggedbottom

\begin{document}

\frontmatter

\begin{frontespizio}
%\Preambolo{\renewcommand{\fronttitlecolor}{black}}
\Universita{name_univ}
%\Logo{}
\Divisione{School of}
\Scuola{M.Sc. in}
\Titolo{Explaining overbidding in first price \protect\\ interdependent values auctions using  \protect\\  regret}
\NCandidato{Author}
\Candidato[]{name aut}
\NRelatore{Thesis advisor}{}
\Relatore{Prof}
\Piede{Academic year }
\end{frontespizio}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Please, make a complete compilable example. With the complete title, too.

Comment: @egreg Just of the frontespizio file or of the main file?

Comment: Main file up to (and including) the `frontespizio` environment. Only the essential packages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need some judgment here, so a very late decision when everything is in final form.

The title is justified, so you can act on the `\rightskip` parameter:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[suftesi]{frontespizio}

\begin{document}

\begin{frontespizio}
%\Preambolo{\renewcommand{\fronttitlecolor}{black}}
\Universita{nameuniv}
%\Logo{}
\Divisione{School of}
\Scuola{M.Sc. in}
\Titolo{%
  \setlength{\rightskip}{1em}%
  Explaining overbidding in first price
  interdependent values auctions using
  regret}
\NCandidato{Author}
\Candidato[]{name aut}
\NRelatore{Thesis advisor}{}
\Relatore{Prof}
\Piede{Academic year }
\end{frontespizio}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: That's interesting. How can allowing more stretchable space at the right of line endings cause the right endings of these lines to be aligned?

Comment: @Al-MotasemAldaoudeyeh It's not stretchable

Answer (score 0):

[image]

Use `tabularx` environment to get the needed alignment. Here is the code:

```
\newlength{\defaulttabcolsep}
\setlength{\defaulttabcolsep}{\tabcolsep}

\setlength{\tabcolsep}{0pt}
\begin{tabularx}{1\columnwidth}{>{\Large}c >{\Large}r}

    \justifying
    Explaining overbidding in first & price \\
    interdependent values auctions\mbox{ }& using \\

\end{tabularx}
\setlength{\tabcolsep}{\defaulttabcolsep}
```

`\mbox{ }` is used to add normal space because that is not added automatically just by pressing spacebar. Note that `\tabcolsep` is used to specify half the separation between columns and the default value varies by the document type. You just need to suppress that separation temporarily and then recover its default value with `\setlength{\tabcolsep}{\defaulttabcolsep}`.

You will also need to add `tabularx` package to the preamble